# Area of a rectangular triangle

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

We need to calculate the area of the triangle shown in figure:

[image]

The text of the problem also says that: $\sin \alpha =2 \sin \beta$. What is the area of ​​the triangle?

Comment: Hint: name the sides a, b.  Remember that $a^2+b^2=h^2$.  Use the definition of $\sin\alpha$ in terms of sides and find the relationship between the sides.  Finally compute $\frac{ab}2$

Comment: But my professor told me that I can not use the relations: $a=20 \cos \alpha, a=20 \sin \beta$ etc. How do I solve the exercise without using this relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: the law is sines tells you one leg is twice the other. If the short one is $x$, apply the Pythagorean theorem to find $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Opposite to $\alpha$ is $a$ and opposite to $\beta$ is $b$
Then $\sin \alpha=a/20, \sin \beta =b/20$
By given $\sin \alpha=2\sin \beta $
$\implies a/20  = 2*b/20\implies a=2b$
By Pythagorean theorem $a^2+b^2=20^2$
$\implies (2b)^2 +b^2 =400$
$\implies 5b^2 =400$
$\implies b=\sqrt {80}$
$\implies a=2\sqrt {80}$
$area=(1/2)*b*a $
$\implies area=80$ sq cms